# Need to create "Custom dimensions" in GA4 to track Articles (Users & PV) written by our writer

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I am looking to get "Editor name" & "Published date" data from GA4 as we are already getting it from existing UA GA. Please see attached screen shot for the same.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eaZ49.jpg)

Also, guide me how can we do this via GTM? (Step by step - As I am new in GTM)

Please see attached screenshot of what details we are getting from existing UAGA but I need to get same details from GA4. Please help me.

Site - dailynews360 (Hindi news portal)

I tried few things but still not getting success. Please see attached screen shot for the same. [[Create custom dimesions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGJ53.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eG7wx.jpg)[Add some parameters in GA4  script]
[Data not Available  script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hnh7i.jpg)

Please see What exact report i need. Please see attached screen shot.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eaZ49.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want to track `page_view` with additional event parameter

You can try

1. add this code to disable the auto tracking page_view

```
gtag('set', 'send_page_view', false);
```

2. add the page_view tracking manually.

```
gtag("event", "page_view", {
  editor_name: $your_editor_name,
  pub_date: $pud_date
});
```

Then check if the event_parameters show as expected

Comment: Came across this after hours of agonozing search and probing through GA4, GA's own docs, and blog posts all regurgitating the steps to create a custom dimension in GA—just the dashboard part. Thanks!

Also, I was able to send my custom data (like the native `content_type`) without disabling the automatic page view tracking part (step 1). Just added this.

```javascript
gtag('event', 'page_view', {
  'content_type': $content_type,
})
```

Comment: If you don't disable the auto tracking `page_view` and send another `page_view` event. You need to make sure there is no duplicate `page_view` events. If you don't want to disable the auto tracking. There is another way like https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/gtagjs/reference#set . Using `set` is another workaround

Comment: Thanks for this answer. This is gonna help me too. There's also a GA4-specific page describing the same thing a little differently: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ga4/views?client_type=gtag